# How to stop StackOverflowException and access buttons from MainWindow?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, stack-overflow

I am making a  tic tac toe program (first WPF and I'm relatively new to coding) and I am getting a stack overflow exception when I try to run this. (I am only pasting the relevant code below, not everything) I'm pretty sure it has to do with the part that says MainWindow mWW = new MainWindow, but I am not sure how else to access the buttons without doing that. If anyone could add input it would help a lot.

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        win();
    }

     private static void win()
    {
        var mWW = new MainWindow();
        if (xWin == true)
        {
            mWW.lblWin.Content = "X's Wins!";
        }
        else if (oWin == true)
        {
            mWW.lblWin.Content = "O's Wins!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `turn()` call `win()`? Please share `turn()` with us. Are you sure you want to create a brand new (and completely separate) `MainWindow` in `win()`? It seems likely you just want to change the current one (use the `this` keyword).

Comment: `MainWindow()` calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()` (see `var mWW = new MainWindow();`), which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, which calls `win()`, which calls `MainWindow()`, and so on.

Comment: I accidentally included the wrong  class there. Instead of  win() I called turn(). I just fixed it to say what it is supposed to. And how would I use the this keyword? Would it be like this.lblWin.Content = "O's Wins!";

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it would be like.

Comment: It looks like you decided to fix your `object reference required for non-static` by creating a new instance. Very wrong. You should have fixed it by making the `win()` method non-static (i.e. remove the `static` keyword). That said, it looks like you're using WPF and so the whole approach is wrong anyway; it's doubtful that you should check for a win in the `InitializeComponent()` method, and it's _definitely_ the case that you shouldn't be accessing UI elements to set content. Learn about MVVM and data binding and use WPF correctly. It'll be way easier in the long run, though harder at first.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks, but if you're making a `new MainWindow()` somewhere else in the program outside of `win()` you should be able to reference the existing `MainWindow()` instance. Like @Llama said you're essentially entering an infinite recursion sequence, because `MainWindow()` calls `win()`, and you're creating a `MainWindow()` inside `win()`. You're probably going to need to create the `MainWindow()` somewhere outside of `win()` and reference it.